# why one bteq script works, but not the other

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Below are two similar codes, why the first one is working but not the 2nd one please? The expected output should be 2017/05/14 for both codes. Can anyone please explain the usage of curly brackets (at # line 2) after the round brackets?

```
> vi varoutput.bt
query_td () {  # line 2 
bteq << EOBTQ |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
.LOGON TDPROD/userid,pass;
select '>'||t.cal_dt from rldmprod_v.cal_dt t where t.cal_dt=current_date;
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOBTQ
}
var=$(query_td)
echo $var

 > ksh varoutput.bt
 2017/05/14

 > vi testoutput4.bt
 testabcd=$(bteq <<EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
 .LOGON TDPROD/userid,pass;

select '>'||t.cal_dt from rldmprod_v.cal_dt t where t.cal_dt=current_date;

.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOF
)
var=$testabcd
echo $var
> ksh testoutput4.bt  # I expect the output is 2017/05/14
*** Failure 5628 Column > not found in rldmprod_v.t.
            Statement# 1, Info =0
```

Comment: Please edit your Q to show expected output. Also, can you add near the top just the line of code that illustrates your 2nd Q, "please explain the usage of curly brackets after the round brackets". We shouldn't have to try and guess which lines you are asking about. Good luck!

Comment: Both scripts work for me.  `query_td ()` defines a function with all commands between `{` and `}`.